# Adding preferences to Mac app

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have created a Mac app, now I want to add a Preferences to this. I looked up and came to know that I need to use NSPreferencePane. I have created a separate Xcode project for this and it will get generate a .prefPane file. On running this it will ask whether to add to system preferences or not and adds it if selected.

How can I bundle my app and preferences together ?
If I package this as a dmg file should I put both .app anf .prefPane file in the dmg file ?

Comment: Does anything in [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/userexperience/Conceptual/PreferencePanes/PreferencePanes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000110i) help with your question?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to magically (or programmatically) copy the preference pane into the right place (`~/Library/PreferencePanes` or `/Library/PreferencePanes`).

If you're going to copy it into your user's Preference Pane folder (i.e. `~/Library/PreferencePanes`), you should be able to simply copy it from your Application bundle into there.

If you want to copy it into a system-wide Preference Pane folder (i.e. `/Library/PreferencePanes`), you'll need to write a privileged tool or helper app that gets Administrator priviledges so it can do the copy. [Creating these things is not the most trivial of tasks](http://ideveloper.co/designing-writing-and-deploying-a-privileged-helper-on-mac-os-x/).

If you are ***not*** distributing via the Apple App Store, you could use an installer package to install both your application and your preference pane. The newest option from Apple is ["`productbuild`"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/productbuild.1.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/1/productbuild), which is a command line tool. PackageMaker is Apple's older tool for creating installers, and you can get it as part of the Auxillary Tools for Xcode, available from [the Downloads section of developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action), and there are a bunch of other installer-building tools you could use to ship your Preference Pane with your app, such as ["Iceberg"](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Iceberg.html).

Comment: can you even do it when going via MAS? don't think you are allowed to in that case.

Comment: [If you look at the MAS guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/mac/resources/approval/guidelines.html), the section that seems to apply is 2.15... "apps must be self-contained, single application installation bundles, and cannot install code or resources in shared locations".  That leaves the "installs into the user's home directory (or local) preference pane folder" question open for interpretation.

Comment: I always read it as :: may not install anything else anywhere  :)

Answer (score -1):

It would be much easier to simply add the preferences interface to the app itself.